# How can I make this progress bar in wordpress? Any plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, progress-bar

I am developing a real-estate wordpress website. I want to make a progress bar which will show the current progress of the project being completed. Time left for phase completion and the amount required to invest in that phase.

[Sample Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urYKE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use html with a bit of php for that. $points is the value between min and max. Style it up with a bit off css and make sure the width is set.

```
<div class="progress-bar red-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $points; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="499"></div>
```